# Play 2 Javascript Router with Arguments

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.6

I've got this method:

```
showHome(categories: Option[String],
           query: Option[String],
           sort: Option[Int],
           page: Option[Int],
           platform: Option[String])
```

Now I want to call this from the javascript router.  I'm not sure what to input because I can't represent Options in javascript.

```
window.location = jsRoutes.controllers.Application.showHome(CATEGORY_STRING, "test", newSort, null);
```

throws this error:

```
Illegal request-target: Invalid input '[', expected segment, '/', '?' or 'EOI' (line 1, column 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got it. To redirect I've to get the absolute url.

```
jsRoutes.controllers.Application.showHome(CATEGORY_STRING, QUERY_STRING, newSort, null).absoluteURL()
```